# Hyper-V isolation not activated in Windows Server version 1803

Tags: azure, docker, hyper-v

I am trying to run **Windows Server 2016** containers on a **Windows Server version 1803** *Service Fabric cluster* in **Hyper-V isolation** mode, but it fails with:

> No hypervisor is present on this system.

It seems that the **docker daemon** is not configured and needs to be activated for hyper-v isolation. How can I active Hyper-V on the Windows Server (Datacenter-Core-1803-with-Containers-smalldisk)?

**DETAILS**

*HOST OS on ServiceFabric node*

```
Publisher: MicrosoftWindowsServer
Offer: WindowsServerSemiAnnual
SKU: Datacenter-Core-1803-with-Containers-smalldisk
Version: 1803.0.20181017
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
BuildLabEx    REG_SZ    17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
```

*CONTAINER OS*

```
Windows Server 2016, builds 14393 (Long-Term Servicing Channel)
```

*Docker Command*

`docker run --isolation=hyperv -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016 cmd`

> Error response from daemon: container Error response from daemon:
>   container
>   0499ef6e3f17843644323fa62b822fd30b89cc8f4ac2ab7d05396fec51252ac7
>   encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows
>   system call: No hypervisor is present on this system.

**EDIT**

Hyper-V is installed, I checked that with the following command:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName xxx
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do nested virtualization on the **Dv3** and **Ev3** VM sizes. The Dv3 and Ev3 sizes are also some of the first VM’s to be running on Windows Server 2016 hosts.  Windows 2016 hosts enable Nested Virtualization and Hyper-V Containers for these new VM sizes.  Nested virtualization allows you to run a Hyper-V server on an Azure virtual machine. With nested virtualization you can run a Hyper-V Container in a virtualized container host, set-up a Hyper-V lab in a virtualized environment, or to test multi-machine scenarios. You can find more information on [Nested Virtualization on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/).